# Test Prep Question: Finding average rate of consumption

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a test prep question for a high school student:

Kimberly drives at a rate of $50$ miles per hour on her trip across the country. If it takes Kimberly $200$ gallons of gasoline to drive $500$ miles, how many minutes will it take her to use $x$ gallons of gasoline if she uses gasoline at the same average rate of consumption?

A) $20x$

B) $3/x$

C) $x/20$

D) $3x$

I get Answer D ($3x$) by cancelling the dimensions so I end up with minutes.

Can some please let me know if that seems right? And maybe another way to explain this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

In terms of easier wording, I can't think of a way. In my opinion, wordy math problems are less about mathematical ability, and more about reading comprehension. When working with weird quantities, the only way it to go by the units. Maybe I'm a moron in this respect, but during my bachelors in physics, as well as in my professional life, units are often the only way I know/knew what quantities I was working with.

I have probably solved your question in a very similar way as you:

1. We know $\frac{200}{500}$gl/mi, and we know $50$mi/h $=\frac{50}{60}$mi/min from the set-up.
2. We multiply to get gallons per minute (because we know we need this relationship from the question), in order to set up the right fraction value: $\frac{2}{5}*\frac{5}{6}*$gl/mi * mi/min$=\frac{1}{3}$gl/min.

3. We know that we need to multiply $x$ gallons by min/gl to get minutes, so we need to take the reciprocol of the above (gl/min -> min/gl), and we get the desired $3x$.